# EntityFramework context returning old data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on an ASP.NET web forms project that has an implementation of a user repository that is acting strangely. I'm experiencing the following behavior:

1. User logs in with a valid username/password. They get in successfully.
2. User logs out.
3. I change the password in the database (for argument's sake).
4. User logs in again using the new password. However, the login is rejected as invalid.

If I set a breakpoint at the "user" variable in the ValidateUser() method and inspect the password, it has the OLD password even though the database clearly has the new password saved. It seems to me like there's some problem with the architecture of the repository that is causing it to load an old context or something along those lines, but it creates a new PortalContext() each time the class is instantiated. Any ideas?

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected readonly PortalContext Context = new PortalContext();
}

public class UserRepository : BaseRepository, IUserRepository
{
    public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
       var user = Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginName == username);

       if (user == null) return false;
       return user.Password == password;
    }
}
```

.NET CODE BEHIND

```
public partial class _default
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository = new UserRepository();

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_userRepository.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
        {
            // Log user in
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If I update ValidateUser() to the following code, the problem goes away. This seems to confirm that it has something to do with it hanging on to the old context.

```
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (var context = new PortalContext())
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginName == username);

        if (user == null) return false;
        return user.Password == password;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems very strange to me. I think the code you provided is correct. The problem seems to be somewhere else obviously...

Comment: I would agree, except there's not much else to it. The code behind makes a call to _userRepository.ValidateUser() which queries the database to see if the login is valid. ValidateUser() is returning false after the user has been loaded before and the password has changed.

Comment: Are you completely sure that every request get's a new instance of the repository? And how do you change the user record in the db? Also through the Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, every request gets a new instance (I set a breakpoint to be sure). The password is changed through the same repository, however it doesn't matter if I change it through code or just a manual change in the database. Once the ValidateUser() has been called for a particular user, calling it again once the password has changed fails, no matter what mechanism was used to change it.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the ValidateUser method and see what values come from the database the second time when the login fails

Comment: I did, that was the whole point of the original post. The second time, the entity has the old password.

Comment: What's happening when you restart the application after changing the password?

Comment: It works once the app pool is restarted -- once. Then the second and all subsequent times it fails again.

Comment: Then some caching is enabled somewhere in your application.

Comment: There is no caching enabled for this application. If I change the username in the database, in ValidateUser(), user == null so I know it's going to the database to at least check for the record...

Comment: Please show your database write code.

Comment: The code to change the password doesn't matter. The same behavior exists if I just manually change it in the SQL Management Studio.

Comment: So this is a SQL Server Connection issue, I suggest you highlight this in your question's title.

Comment: EF does cache queries with the same paremeter

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue. The problem is that MembershipProvider is instantiated only once and you probably created context in its constructor and thats why it works when you moved your context initialization in method ValidateUser.

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework only looks for changes if one of the entity key's has changed.

When I had a similar issue, I made the dateModified field (every table I make such a field to track when it was changed) as a entity key, since then all changes are coming in perfect and fast. in the same context instance.